# remove the text line "powered by InstantSearch+" in magento

Tags: magento

Hi i have this InstantSearch+ extension in magento. Ive downloaded and installed in my magento site. The InstantSearch+ works fine in the search bar. My problem is i want to remove the text line "Powered by InstantSearch+". Here is my screenshot

[image]

Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 InstantSearch Dashboard -  Apps Settings > Premium Settings > Show "Powered by InstantSearch+" logo in results.
```

If you're not using their premium version you'll have to get clever with some CSS.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply i have seen it from my settings and this is the only settings ive seen here
http://awesomescreenshot.com/09046hsh05

Comment: Try the link to the dashboard?

Comment: where can i find that?

Comment: I can see the link in grey on your screenshot

Comment: what do you mean linki in grey?

Comment: ahh ive seen the grey link your talking about when i go to that link and tried to login i cannot login and tried to change password using the email ive use cannot received in email too :(

Comment: hello ive already logged in, in the dashboard i cannot find to turn of the text line "powered by instantSearch+"